# OpenID check_authentication not working

Tags: php, openid

I'm trying to write my own provider in PHP (JanRain libraries are confusing as all hell, and even phpMyID doesn't document *exactly* what is happening).  I've got authentication working, but when the relying party tries to do check_authentication, it says my server denied it.

This is debugging information I captured during a check_authentication request.

```
$_GET:
Array
(
    [mode] => profile
    [username] => jrhodes
    [domain] => roket-enterprises.com
)
$_POST:
Array
(
    [openid_assoc_handle] => {HMAC-SHA1}{4abdf2f1}{olw8ag==}
    [openid_identity] => http://www.roket-enterprises.com/openaccount/openid:jrhodes
    [openid_mode] => check_authentication
    [openid_response_nonce] => 2009-09-26T10:54:41ZLg0kfQ
    [openid_return_to] => http://www.wasab.dk/morten/2007/11/openid/?janrain_nonce=2009-09-26T10%3A54%3A37Z9rZCkP&openid1_claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.roket-enterprises.com%2Fopenaccount%2Fopenid%3Ajrhodes
    [openid_sig] => Xl94j3IJtfSEQ4oKfova68I8edc=
    [openid_signed] => assoc_handle,identity,mode,response_nonce,return_to,signed,sreg.email,sreg.fullname,sreg.nickname
    [openid_sreg_email] => jrhodes@roket-enterprises.com
    [openid_sreg_fullname] => James Rhodes
    [openid_sreg_nickname] => jrhodes
)

 Using Specific Mode Endpoint Handler...
  Answering check_authentication
Headers:
  Content-Type: text/plain;
  openid.mode: id_res;
  openid_mode: id_res;
  sreg.fullname: James Rhodes;
  sreg.nickname: jrhodes;
  sreg.email: jrhodes@roket-enterprises.com;
  is_valid: true;
```

The GET and POST data is the data that my script is receiving.  Everything after "Headers:" are the headers that my script is returning.  According to the specifications, I can't see anything wrong with this.

I've been asking on #openid for the last 4 hours and haven't got a response (note to self: post on StackOverflow, then ask IRC).  Can anyone help?